# How can I get the the sum of all combined word lengths to print as a single value?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having trouble converting the total of all word counts. I have tried various methods, the length per word is correct, I just can't get a total?

```
file=open(r"sheSaid.txt","r+")
from collections import Counter
wordcount = Counter(file.read().split())
for word in file.read().split(' '):
    word = word.rstrip(".""',?!")
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

#print (word.rstrip(".""..',?!"),wordcount)
for item in wordcount.items(): print("{}\t{}".format(*item))
wordCount = len(wordcount)

#can count all word lengths just fine
print ("The total word count is:", word, wordCount) # when I use Len() Or #Count I cannot get the sum of all wordCounts?
print ("The total length of all words are:","total_of_all_word_counts?")

#I need the sum to complete this
print ("The avg length is:", wordcount/total_of_all_word_counts?)
file.close();
```

Comment: I need to #(1) Strip out all punctuation (including periods, apostrophes, quotation marks, commas, etc.).
#(2) Count the words.
#(3) Add up the total length of all the words.
#(4) Calculate the average word length.
#(5) Output the values you calculated in steps 2,3,4 above. Be sure to preface each value ach value
# with info about what the number means (for example, "Total words in the file is 251.")

Comment: You use both python-2.7 and python-3.x together ?!

Comment: the code is not even well identated python code.

Comment: No I have 3  loaded my bad

Comment: This site does not provide that kind of help. You need to seek out a tutoring service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: not use to posting on this forum and useing block quotes I apologize

Comment: I really just need to know how to get the sum of my word count as a total everything I have tried has failed?

Comment: This isn't a forum, it's a QA site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must be useful, clear, and on-topic. "I need help" is none of those, but I'm sure a tutor would know how to proceed.

Comment: @ShaunPritchard to clarify more on what is expected, you should add what you expected but isn't working. If you can't work out some of the task, list what you tried and someone may help accordingly.

Comment: When using `word = word.rstrip(".""',?!")` you are (accidentally?) concatenating two strings: `"."` and `"',?!"`. Most likely you meant to put the `"` character inside the string. To do this, you have to escape it: `word = word.rstrip(".\"',?!")`

Comment: Additionally, you are building a `Counter()` and then manually change the counts. You should do your word cleaning beforehand and then let the Counter do its thing. Also, `import` statements should go to the very top, and your file should be closed as soon as possible, not at the very end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do, although not clear what you are looking for, but this will count the words in the text file, calculate the character count for all words and then the character average:

```
file = open(r"sheSaid.txt","r+")
file_contents = file.read().split()  # Reads the file and split by spaces to create a list of words
file.close()  # Always good idea to close the file after done with it

words_count = len(file_contents)
characters_count = len(''.join(file_contents))
average_characters = characters_count / words_count
```

You may want to do an extra effort and handle some other cases, like removing characters like `!`, `.` etc. That will be straightforward. This is just a starting point to build upon. You only know the corner cases and what will be in the text file.